# OR query in Solr not working

Tags: solr

My Solr server seems only working with AND but not OR, e.g.

```
/solr/select?q=(marsden AND emma)&qt=yodl_handler works, but 
/solr/select?q=(marsden OR mackey)&qt=yodl_handler doesn't.
```

For each individual query, it returns resutls, e.g.

```
/solr/select?q=marsden&qt=yodl_handler returns 2 results
/solr/select?q=mackey&qt=yodl_handler returns 3 results
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Here is the definition of yodl_handler:

```
<requestHandler name="yodl_handler" class="solr.DisMaxRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <float name="tie">0.01</float>
      <str name="qf">
        dc.title^1 dc3.title^1 dc.type^1 vra2.logical.creator^1 vra2.image.agent.name^1 vra2.image.agent.role^1 vra2.image.agent.role^1 vra2.image.location.name^1 vra2.image.rights.rightsholder^1 vra2.image.source.refid^1 vra2.image.title^1 vra2.image.worktype^1 vra2.work.agent.attribution^1 vra2.work.agent.name^1 vra2.work.agent.role^1 vra2.work.culturalContext^1 vra2.work.description^1 vra2.work.location-type^1 vra2.logical.location.place^1 vra2.logical.location.name^1 vra2.work.location.refid^1 vra2.work.material^1 vra2.work.rights.rightsHolder^1 vra2.work.StylePeriod^1 vra2.work.subject.term.name^1 vra2.work.subject.term.place^1 vra2.work.subject.term.keyword^1 vra2.work.technique^1 vra2.work.title^1 vra2.work.worktype^1 iris2.instrument.instrumentType^1 iris2.instrument.primaryInstrumentType^1 iris2.instrument.secondaryInstrumentType^1 iris2.instrument.instrumentType.alltypes^1 iris2.instrument.author^1 iris2.references.allauthors^1 iris2.instrument.researchArea^1 iris2.instrument.typeOfFile^1 iris2.instrument.software^1 iris2.instrument.dataType^1 iris2.instrument.linguisticTarget^1 iris2.instrument.sourceLanguage^1 iris2.instrument.funder^1 iris2.instrument.licence^1 iris2.participants.participantType^1 iris2.participants.firstLanguage^1 iris2.participants.targetLanguage^1 iris2.participants.gender^1 iris2.participants.proficiencyLearner^1 iris2.participants.proficiencyStudentsTaught^1 iris2.participants.yearsOfTeachingExperience^1 iris2.participants.domainOfUse^1 iris2.references.publicationType^1 iris2.references.author^1 iris2.references.author.lastnames^1 iris2.references.booktitle^1 iris2.references.journal^1 iris2.references.publicationDate^1 iris2.references.publicationLatestDate^1 iris2.references.publisher^1 iris2.references.placeOfPublication^1 iris2.references.editor^1 iris2.references.conferenceName^1
      </str>
      <int name="ps">100</int>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
      <str name="hl.fl">text features name</str>
      <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
      <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
      <str name="f.text.hl.fragmenter">regex</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Who set up the `qt=yodl_handler`, since I cannot google it at all. Please ask him, whoever it is :-) Meanwhile, remove that term to get the default query handler.

Comment: That's the definition of yodl_handler:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, the Solr DisMax query parser does not support boolean logic in queries. The appearance of it working with the query involving "AND" is probably a side-effect of the way your fields are indexed (stop words?) or appears in the underlying data.

You can get a better idea what's happening under the hood if you send the debugQuery parameter, e.g.:

> /solr/select?q=(marsden AND emma)&qt=yodl_handler&debugQuery=true

There's further documentation on the Solr wiki about the Dismax parser:

> The Dismax query parser supports an extremely simplified subset of the Lucene QueryParser syntax. Quotes can be used to group phrases, and +/- can be used to denote mandatory and optional clauses ... but all other Lucene query parser special characters are escaped to simplify the user experience. (see [DisMaxQParserPlugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin))

The good news is, if you're using a modern version of Solr (3.1+), you have access to the new [ExtendedDisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) parser, which DOES support boolean queries. `